# C++ std::mem_fn with overloaded member function

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers

When compiling the following code, Visual Studio reports:

```
\main.cpp(21): error C2664: 'std::_Call_wrapper<std::_Callable_pmd<int ClassA::* const ,_Arg0,false>,false> std::mem_fn<void,ClassA>(int ClassA::* const )' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'overloaded-function' to 'int ClassA::* const '
    1>          with
    1>          [
    1>              _Arg0=ClassA
    1>          ]
    1>          Context does not allow for disambiguation of overloaded function
```

Why is the compiler confused when creating `mem_fptr1`? But some how `mem_fptr2` is ok when I specify the types.

Can I create member function pointer to an overloaded member function that takes no argument?

```
class ClassA
{
public:
    void memberfunction()
    {
        std::cout <<"Invoking ClassA::memberfunction without argument" << std::endl;
    }

    void memberfunction(int arg)
    {
        std::cout << "Invoking ClassA::memberfunction with integer " << arg << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto mem_fptr1 = std::mem_fn<void, ClassA>(&ClassA::memberfunction);
    auto mem_fptr2 = std::mem_fn<void, ClassA, int>(&ClassA::memberfunction);

    mem_fptr1(ClassA());
    mem_fptr2(ClassA(), 3);
}
```

Comment: Note that on gcc, both versions give errors. What version of Visual Studio are you using? Why are you using std::mem_fn instead of a lambda? Since you are using auto, clearly it's a reasonably modern compiler and you needn't trifle with the almost entirely out-classed std::mem_fn, std::bind, etc.

Comment: @metal, Visual Studio 2013

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [template overloads taking a variadic list of argument types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn) were introduced in C++11 but removed in C++14 as [defect #2048](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2048).  The way to specify a particular overload is to specify a function type as the first template argument (the second template argument, the class type, can be omitted as it can be deduced):

```
auto mem_fptr1 = std::mem_fn<void()>(&ClassA::memberfunction);
auto mem_fptr2 = std::mem_fn<void(int)>(&ClassA::memberfunction);
```

The function type `R` is then composed with the class type `T` as `R T::*` to give the member function type. This also allows forming a `std::mem_fn` to a data member (where `R` is a non-function type).

Note that your code (for `mem_fptr2`) does not work in C++14 where the template overloads taking a variadic list of argument types are removed; the above code will work in both versions of the Standard.

An alternative is to perform a member function cast; in this case you do not need to specify template arguments to `mem_fn`:

```
auto mem_fptr1 = std::mem_fn(
    static_cast<void (ClassA::*)()>(&ClassA::memberfunction));
auto mem_fptr2 = std::mem_fn(
    static_cast<void (ClassA::*)(int)>(&ClassA::memberfunction));
```

Comment: Great Answer +1. How can I find these information on my own? Does the standard cover these?

Comment: @FrankLiu I got this information from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn - it's one of the better references out there and covers differences between versions of the Standard.

Comment: @ectmur, emm..., I read the same website but I didnt work out the answer. In their example, auto c = std::mem_fn<int&()>(&X::get ); there is no static_cast, they didnot specify the class name as the second template argument.

Comment: @FrankLiu well, the second template argument can be deduced from the function argument.

Comment: @ectmur, auto mem_fptr1 = std::mem_fn<void(), ClassA>(&ClassA::memberfunction); gives error C2770 by VS 2013

Comment: @FrankLiu that appears to be a defect in MSVC (rather, in its library); you'll have to use the `static_cast` method.