# Get reference to member function overloaded by const specification

Tags: c++, c++11

Here is some class with two overloaded methods foo:

```c++
class Object {
public:
    Object (double someVal) : val(someVal) { }
    double getter () const { return val; }
    double& getter () { return val; }
private:
    double val;
};
```

So now the `double Object::getter() const` function will be called on const instances

```c++
const Object instance(42);
cout << instance.getter() << endl; // called: `double getter() const`
```

Now, I am trying to get reference to `double getter() const` function and assign it to `std::function` type

```c++
const Object instance(42);
function<double(const Object&)> foo = &Object::getter;
cout << foo(instance) << endl;
```

The code works fine if function `double& getter()` is removed, but with it I got the following error on the second line:

```
test.cpp:18:34: error: no viable conversion from '<overloaded function type>' to
      'function<double (const Object &)>'
        function<double(const Object&)> foo = &Object::getter;
                                        ^     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

It seems that error happens, because system tries to call `double& getter()`.
The question is how to force calling of `double getter() const`?
The full listing is attached [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13WL4OGWZVx2vT8PxSnFmsOZdufBCKT2l/view)

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25765053/c-stdmem-fn-with-overloaded-member-function

Comment: Yes. I have tried two variants. Both fails:
1.    function<double(Object::*)()> foo = static_cast<double(Object::*)()>(&Object::getter);
2.    function<double(Object::*)()const> foo = static_cast<double(Object::*)()const>(&Object::getter);

Answer (score 3):

By casting to the specific function pointer type:

```
std::function<double(const Object&)> foo = static_cast<double(Object::*)() const>(&Object::getter);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use a lambda closure:

```
Object o{0.0};
std::function<double()> f = [o](){ return o.getter(); };
```

The lambda calls the const version of `getter()`, as captured variables are `const` by default (otherwise you'd have to use `mutable`).

Comment: Oh, that's clever. Where would `mutable` go if you were interested in using the non-const version?

Comment: @Ruzhim: thanks. The `mutable` comes behind the parameters, i.e. `std::function<double()> f = [o]() mutable { return o.getter(); };` calls the non-const version of `getter()`.

Answer (score 2):

[Address of Overload functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overloaded_address) defined 7 contexts where the correct overload can be deduced. Yet `std::function<...>` is not one of them. Thus, the overload function to get address of is ambiguous.

There are a few ways to select the overload you want:

```cpp
const Object instance(42);
// Use static_cast to select overload
std::function<double(const Object&)> foo = static_cast<double(Object::*)() const>(&Object::getter);
// Use lambda to select overload
// std::function type parameters can be omitted since c++ 17
// Guaranteed copy elision since c++ 17
std::function bar = [](const Object& instance) { return instance.getter(); };
// Use std::mem_fn
std::function<double(const Object&)> mfn = std::mem_fn<double() const>(&Object::getter);
```

---

However, an idiomatic way to declare methods with similar functionality but differed by constness is actually to declare two different functions: `foo()` and `cfoo()`. Think about `begin()` and `cbegin()`. The latter returns a const iterator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a typedef to disambiguate the function you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class Object {
public:
    Object (double someVal) : val(someVal) { }
    double getter () const { return val; }
    double& getter () { return val; }
private:
    double val;
};

typedef double (Object::*funtype)() const;

int main()
{
    const Object instance(42);
    std::function<double(const Object&)> foo = static_cast<funtype>(&Object::getter);
    std::cout << foo(instance) << std::endl;
}
```

[run on cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/3whtt)

Or, without casting:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class Object {
public:
    Object (double someVal) : val(someVal) { }
    double getter () const { return val; }
    double& getter () { return val; }
private:
    double val;
};

typedef double (Object::*funtype)() const;

int main()
{
    const Object instance(42);
    funtype temp = &Object::getter;
    std::function<double(const Object&)> foo = temp;
    std::cout << foo(instance) << std::endl;
}
```

[run on cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/5dwci)

Answer (score 0):

Yet another example, going through some options.

```
// auto mem_fn = static_cast<double (Object::*)() const>(&Object::getter);
// or shorter:
double (Object::*mem_fn)() const = &Object::getter;

// store member function (without instance)
std::function<double(const Object&)> foo = mem_fn;
std::cout << foo(instance) << "\n";

// bind with instance
auto bound = std::bind(mem_fn, &instance);
std::cout << bound() << "\n";

// store member function (with instance)
std::function<double()> bar = bound;
std::cout << bar() << "\n";

// store member function (with instance), without the intermediate steps
std::function<double()> baz =
    std::bind(
        static_cast<double (Object::*)() const>(&Object::getter),
        instance
    );
std::cout << baz() << "\n";
```